# $(\mathbb{R},T)$ metrizable?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

> Let $T$ be the topology generated by the $[a,b)$ with $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Is $(\mathbb{R},T)$ metrizable?

I am not sure. I was thinking about applying Urysohn's Metrization. This space is definitely Hausdorff. I also think it is second-countable (take rational endpoints). I am not sure if it is regular.

Am I even on the right track?

Comment: Oops, overlooked the rationality condition. I only noticed $[a,b)$ and thought "lower limit topology".

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you think it is second countable?

Comment: Yes, and indeed the intervals with both endpoints rational form a basis.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is it regular? I am not sure how to imagine closed sets in this space.

Comment: Can you see that $[a,b)$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ is clopen?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes

Comment: @DanielFishcher So, it should be regular?

Comment: So, does every point have a neighbourhood base consisting of closed neighbourhoods?

Comment: Yes, This answers my question. Put this this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the intervals $[a,b)$ with both endpoints rational give a countable basis of the topology. And these intervals are clopen, thus every point has a neighbourhood basis consisting of closed neighbourhoods, i.e. the space is regular.

Comment: Again, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

This space has a countable base $$\{[a,b): a , b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

as $$[a,b)= \bigcup\{[a,c): a < c < b, c \in \Bbb Q\}$$ so we can write all generating open sets as a union of basic open sets.

All $[a,b), a,b \in \Bbb Q$ are clopen, so $\Bbb R$ is regular in this topology, as we have a local base of closed sets. Then Urysohn implies
that our space is metrisable.

It's also quite clear that $\Bbb R$ has no local base of compact neighbourhoods at any point. It is also quite clear that our space is Baire but it is completely metrisable, it would follow by a classical theorem that $\Bbb R$ in this topology is homeomorphic to the irrationals in the usual topology. So that would for me be the interesting question here: is it completely metrisable?